# How to set the Text in textView to a text in .txt file

Tags: android, xml, textview

If I have a `TextView`, for example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@text/text.txt"/>
```

How do I set the text to the text in that .txt file.
Or is there an alternative?

Comment: why do you put the text in a txt file rather than in the strings.xml file?

Comment: because it's a really long text

Comment: @hjaltist : You have to do it dynamically (in other words read the text file with code and call `setText(...)`). Also, remember the `strings.xml` file is only a text file anyway - so what difference would it make if you simply stored it in there?

Comment: if it fits in a textview, it fits in an xml strings file

Comment: @Squonk, thanks but I have the text written in strings.xml but I think it's hard to write and edit it here, was just wondering if there was an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way of directly assign a `.txt` file to `textview` in `XML`. But you can read the `.txt` file dynamically via `java`. To read the `.txt` file put your `.txt` file in `/assets` directory, & access like that...

```
AssetManager assetMananger = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetMananger.open("file.txt");
System.out.println(inputStream);
```

Hope this will help you.